# Sorting binary array using comparisons in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to implement a solution to sort a binary array containing 0 and 1 but it is comparison based. I am going with the approach take 1 index i (1st element of array) and 2nd index j last element of array. if i>j swap that element. else increment i and decrement j.
I am pretty new in java and programming.
Here is what I have tried until now:
My sort method:

```
public static void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        int i = arr[0];
        int j = arr[arr.length-1];
        for(int x=0;x<arr.length-1;x++)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            if(i>j)
            {
                temp = i;
                i=j;
                j=temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            else{
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
```

My main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] binary = {0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0};
        sort(binary);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why not just sum the array (gives you the # of 1s) to N and then set the values from 0 to N-1 to 0, and N to length-1 to 1?

Comment: @Avi that requires two passes. partitioning requires one pass

Comment: @mangusta That sounds about right. I just came up with something off the top of my head, but I guess I'll take a look.

Comment: There are many ways,like count the number of 0's and 1 etc..but I want to try using this method

Comment: @Shahrukh One thing I see right away is that you're not accessing the array to read or set values. i and j are set exactly once (from the array), after which point the array is never updated nor read from again.

Comment: additionally his increments/decrements are not correct since i and j point to elements, not indexes

Comment: yes..that's because it's my second week since I have started coding..sorry for that

Comment: You also don't want to increment both index variables at the same time, because you run into a problem where both arr[i] and arr[j] are 1 (you completely skip over those values). That is, the algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: So instead of for loop,should another loop be used? Like while or something?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is that method supposed to be doing? You only ever extract the first and last value of the `arr` array, never look at any of the other values in the array, and never update any values in the array, so in what way is that possibly a method for sorting the array? If you remove all statements inside the method, the *effect* of calling the method is exactly the same as now, i.e. nothing, except it completes much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the problems explained in the comments, I mocked up a solution to show how you might go about doing this correctly. I've also added some comments to explain the logic:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] binary = {0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0};
    sort(binary);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(binary));
  }

  public static void sort(int[] arr)
  {
    int i = 0;
    int j = arr.length - 1;
    while(i < j)
    {
      //we only want to swap 1s to the right
      if(arr[i] == 0)
      //skip 0s
        i++;
      //we only want to swap 1s into places where 0s are
      else if(arr[j] == 1)
      //skip 1s
        j--;
      //if arr[i] is 1 and arr[j] is 0
      else //we now know that arr[i] is 1 and arr[j] is 0
      {
        //move the 1 to the right
        swap(arr, i, j);
        //we just processed arr[i]
        i++;
        //we just processed arr[j]
        j--;
      }
    }
  }

  private static void swap(int[] arr, int idx1, int idx2)
  {
    int temp = arr[idx1];
    arr[idx1] = arr[idx2];
    arr[idx2] = temp;
  }
}
```

This can also be expressed in terms of a for loop, like so (though it's not recommended to make your code this hard to read):

```
public static void sort(int[] arr)
{
  for(int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i += arr[i]^1, j -= arr[j])
    if(arr[i] == 1 && arr[j] == 0)
      swap(arr, i, j);
}
```

When I say "not recommended", recall the saying: "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should."

As per @Andreas' comment, you can just do:

```
arr[i] = 0;
arr[j] = 1;
```

instead of calls to swap. Alternatively for the dirty "not recommended" version, you can do:

```
arr[i] ^= arr[j] = 1;
```

Comment: Why call `swap`? Why not just `arr[i] = 0; arr[j] = 1;`?

Comment: @Andreas He wanted swaps: "if i>j swap that element. else increment i and decrement j."

Comment: But as your comment says *"we now know that arr[i] is 1 and arr[j] is 0"*, so since you **know** the values, you can forego the `temp` variable needed for a *swap*, and just assign the *known* values to effectively get the same result as a swap.

Comment: Fair enough. I've left both approaches there, but it's best to directly assign the values since you know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  I simply start at the top and bottom and separately increment the indices until the conditions are met.  Then replace the values.

```java
      int[] b = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      };

      int a = 0;
      int c = b.length - 1;
      while (a < c) {
         boolean flag1 = true;
         boolean flag2 = true;
         if (b[a] == 0) {
            a++; // leave it there
            flag1 = false;
         }
         //
         if (b[c] == 1) {
            c--; // leave it there
            flag2 = false;
         }
         if (flag1 && flag2) {
            b[c] = 1;
            b[a] = 0;
         }
      }
```